# How to create a database table in an installation file for a Drupal Module?

Tags: database, drupal, module

I am creating a module for Drupal 7.x, and I want to create a database table when the module is installed (enabled for the first time). How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to implement `install_schema` and `uninstall_schema` hooks in your module that return schema information.  These are translated into table create and drop and executed by Drupal when your module is enabled or uninstalled.  Read more in the [Schema API](http://drupal.org/node/146843).

Comment: And these would go in the .install file of your module. These are for Drupal 5.x, but I think they still apply:

http://drupal.org/node/51220

Comment: As this question is asking specifically about Drupal 7.x this answer is quite misleading, the answer provided by Andrew is more accurate.

Answer (score 7):

Old post, I know, but for the sake of completeness:

hook_install_schema and hook_uninstall_schema are no longer necessary as of drupal 7.x

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi

You can get away with just implementing hook_schema().